# Retrieve rows from DB if Date-Difference condition apply

Tags: mysql, sql, select, datediff

I need to retrieve rows from SQL database where a time-difference condition apply.
Basically I need to retrieve rows where date difference from Now() is < x minutes.

Column datetime has this format: `2022-12-05 15:01:43`

I tried

`SELECT * FROM copytrade WHERE DATEDIFF(minute, datetime, GETDATE() AS DateDiff) < 10`

Using this select I get error "Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'

Is it possible in a single SQL line to achieve this select?
Thanks

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using

Comment: 1) Read [DATEDIFF() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) description. It cannot solve your task. You try to use function like it is implemented in SQL Server which is not applicable on MySQL. 2) Use `WHERE datetime_column >= NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE`.

Comment: I have these 4 rows in column `datetime`:





`2022-12-05 19:30:06 - 
2022-12-05 20:01:43 - 
2022-12-05 21:02:00 - 
2022-12-05 23:05:00 - ` 

I tried with 

`SELECT * FROM copytrade WHERE datetime > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE` 

and it should show me only last row, `2022-12-05 23:05:00` .

But it doesn't. It always returns an empty result